# How can I Omit a specific subtype/property?

Tags: typescript

How can I omit a grandchild property?

Here is a contrived example.

```
interface ILikes {
   article: string,
   page: string,
   userId: number | string,
}

interface IUserData {
   userName: string,
   isAdmin: boolean,
   ...data,
   interests: {
     likes: ILikes,
     saved: {
       ...data
     }
   }
}

const userObj: Omit<IUserData, "interests"> = {
   ...data
}
```

I need to omit likes which is a grandchild property. I can't make likes optional because I use it in other instances.

Comment: Keep it simple. Define a new type `type UserInterests = { saved: any }` without the `likes` property.

Comment: @LinDu Your solution, and making "likes" optional are what I want to avoid. Ideally I would be able to reuse the same interface without changing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
export type DeepKey<
    T,
    K extends keyof T = keyof T
> =
    K extends string ?
    T[K] extends Record<string, unknown>
    ? K | `${K}.${DeepKey<T[K]>}`
    : K
    : never

type DeepOmit<
    T,
    P extends DeepKey<T>,
> =
    P extends `${infer M}.${infer Rest}`
    ? { [O in M]: DeepOmit<T[O & keyof T], Rest extends DeepKey<T[O & keyof T]> ? Rest : never> } extends infer Y
    ? { [K in Exclude<keyof T, M>]: T[K] } extends infer Z ?
    {} extends Y ? Z : {} extends Z ? Y : Y & Z
    : never : never
    : { [K in Exclude<keyof T, P>]: T[K] }

type ABC = {
    a:
    {
        b:
        {
            c: 1,
            d: { e: boolean }
        }, f: 2
    }
}

type A = DeepOmit<ABC, 'a'>
//   ^?

type B = DeepOmit<ABC, 'a.b'>
//   ^?

type C = DeepOmit<ABC, 'a.b.c'>
//   ^?
```

[image]

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAixhgNLEQHgFgAoOMuAFQBoTy5s5QZgA7AEwGc4BrPCAM0pwAvDz6CKJAHwja5Bk1ac4HGFACWLAOZwA-HLIUA2tgC6jEM3ZcASsADG0NvlUbtVOAFcW3FhADuLFIGevRwAD5wAAYAJADe2AC+AHTxGFi4BMZmUolRIQBc9IVwLMAAbsBQJCRIKOiYYADyALbqMESk5NQhAAoWVsrpOHj4FFI0xDLCfQNKXLFxmvxVcACyKfHLq3aqeSG6cHFwRk1wmuumRcOt7WOncABkYogClKYeu-CK1g0Zo8Yzs9eK8JKYZIcvnAimVKlAZIk5r9tlA4ABNA5HE4MC4AURA9gANp42MB8CC3tR1lIrpQTOZET9lCi4AAtPQhOKMyzzdGhdlFLlI5Tsw5o6F856skqw1YwipVErHEznFhwfFEklkikSDy9GlFbIMmrEOqoACCACEAMIiI4hACGBU5IToACNnV06GQ4q7vWR7EUAIyTf3+tiCxhFN0QCCE4AOtWJP1kRIefhFABMIWTxFztWQFrtNzaHSt1o8AHIHZXgsQAPT18gAPX0xAL9UtxcatzLNqrDuSbtrJEbLbbHdQttEJbu5YHQ+S9hHDabZFbQA)

Comment: Looks like a brilliant solution, but I don't want to over-engineer this either.

Comment: I doubt there is other solution that work for all cases without "over-engineer" it. Maybe you can drop the auto complete, but that will make it less safe. You can also drop the prettify.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an interface for your `interests` property and Omit `likes` from that interface. That way it is more readable than creating a special Omit utility type.